# How do you manage object lifetimes in a use-case-centric architecture?

Tags: clean-code, use-case

I've been experimenting with layered, use-case-centric architectures as described in [Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture blog post](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).  Most of the examples I've seen are simple "update the customer record" use cases, which make sense.  Where I get a little lost is when it comes to creating objects.

To make things a little more concrete, suppose we have two use cases (which we model as interactors):

```
begin_operation
end_operation
```

Now, most of the things operations do would be interactors in this design (rather than operation object methods), but operations remain first class objects in their own right.  For instance, operations might need to carry bits of state like a globally unique identifier, a log file, or a list of observers.  So it seems like the `begin_operation` interactor should create some sort of operation entity and the `end_operation` interactor should dispose of it.

The question is then, how do we manage the creation of these objects?  How do we communicate information about them to interactor clients?

I've thought of a couple of possible approaches:

1. Just create a new operation object and pass back a pointer to it (possibly in some sort of obfuscated form).
2. Store operations in a operation repository of some kind and pass back a look-up key.  This isn't entirely different from (1), but at least I could detect when I'm passed an invalid operation handle.

Neither approach seems great to me.  What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Those aren't use cases; they're implementation details.  I think you're going to have to explain your terms a bit better.  Is there such a thing as a "Use Case-Based Architecture?"  Every program has use cases.  You would manage object lifetimes in a "use case based architecture" the same way you would in any other architecture.

Comment: Reading the link would clarify what I mean.  TL;DR: in a use case-centric architecture, the use cases themselves are first class objects.  You could think of it as a variation of the command pattern.  I'll edit the post to try and make it a little more clear.

Comment: Your two implementation details: `begin_operation` and `end-operation` form a [*transaction.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)  I would start there, by studying transactions and [Units of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html).  There isn't anything in that Clean Architecture blog entry that would convince me that transactions would be treated any differently than they would in any other architecture.

Comment: I think you're getting too hung up on the example--I'm just trying to avoid extraneous details here.  The _fundamental problem_ is that I have an interactor that creates an entity that outlives the interactor invocation.  The questions are: (1) how identify the entity to callers, and (2) how do I manage its lifetime?

Comment: Why does the entity outlive the interactor invocation?  Why is that important?

Comment: Because it manages state that will be needed for other interactors.

Comment: Why do you still need the original interactor after you've passed the object to some other interactor?

Comment: Oh, wait.  I get it now.  Store the state in the object, not in the interactor.  That way, you can dispose of the interactor once you've used it.  Yeah, I know.  You're thinking "He really doesn't get it."  That's the peril of using such an abstract example.  A more concrete example (with code) might illuminate the situation better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50149/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-peter-ruderman).

Comment: This question is too vague and abstract. Also, it assumes "uncle bob" has some kind of magic design sauce, which does not exist anywhere.

Comment: Uncle Bob's approach comes with costs and benefits, just like anything else.  I'm trying to understand how it's supposed to work.